# nginx reverse proxy for kibana

Tags: kibana, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using this part in nginx config file

```
 location ~ ^/kibana(.*) {

            rewrite /kibana/(.*) /$1  break;
            proxy_pass http://core-services-local-nginx-ingress-controller.kube-system:80;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host "kibana-service-local";
            }
```

but the issue is ,when i do localhost/kibana/ it is redirecting to localhost/app/kibana and displaying  4o4 not found .

[image]

why it is happening? how to resolve this issue?I want kibana dashboard to come when hitting localhost/kibana/.

Answer (score 0):

set the server.basePath setting in kibana.yml to /kibana.